# Component Exception: Element Type is Invalid, check render Method of app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to make a simple chat app, but for some reason, I keep getting the same error:

> Component Exception: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object... Check the Render method of 'App'

Here is app.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Chat from './components/Chat';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

const stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = ()=>{
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.navigator>
        <stack.screen name = "Main" component={Main}/>
        <stack.screen name = "Chat" component={Chat}/>
      </Stack.navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App
```

And here is index.js

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting `stack.screen` as `stack.Screen` and it will probably solve your problem.

That's because there is no Components/Function named `screen`, since `stack.screen` is undefined you get that error.

edit: also, you should rewrite `Stack.navigator` as `stack.Navigator` for the same reason. Never forget that javascript/JSX is case sensitive.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed. The same error in the same place